VIM shows first character and leading spaces with dirty yellow background color when opening files with root permissions

I'm setting up a new server.
When I'm using standard user rights vi has correct syntax highlighting.
When I'm using root rights (with sudo prefix or on root shell (sudo -s)) the first character of each line and leading space characters are colored with a dirty yellow background:

It happens independent of the file type.
How can I get rid of it?
Thanks/regards,
rund

Which version? (Real vi has no colors, so this must be some version of Vim.) Does this still happen even after :syn off? Does it still remain after :nohl?

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Aug  5 2022 07:43:09)   Including Patches: 1-1763   Modified by Oracle Corporation  
with :syn off the yellow part stays
with :nohl the yellow part is gone.
Funny, after setting :nohl once... it looks like it's gone permanently, even when opening a new terminal? If it will stay this way, everything is fine now.

It could have been an (old) search ? /^. * should match the first char and the first spaces on each line, for exemple. it seems to me that vim "remembers" the last search even between sessions (ymmv)

vim loads its settings from the home directory ($HOME); if you run something via sudo that might not be set to what you are expecting, depending on exactly how you invoke vim, and how sudo is configured.
